# I’m looking for a word or phrase which clearly describes this: a number of dialects of the same language are spoken across a geographical area

Tags: dialects

and, although slightly different from one another, as one crosses them all, from the westernmost to the easternmost of them (or vice-versa) ,  one will observe that they differ from one region to the next in such a way that neighboring dialects are mutually intelligible, but the farther apart the two regions, the  more difficult the communication, to the point where speakers from opposite ends of the spectrum may no longer understand one another.  Is there a word or phrase for this linguistic phenomenon?

Comment: There is a perfect biological analogy that maybe you could use as a metaphor or adapt somehow.  Have a look at the Wiki on "ring species". I hope this helps.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK  Yes, looks like a biological counterpart. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, this is the normal condition of human speech communities, though without the requirement that all be dialects of the same language, which is in practice impossible to determine precisely -- is Catalan a dialect of Spanish or not? Is Swiss German a dialect of German, or a separate language? And we won't even mention Bantu languages, which fade into one another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DIALECT CONTINUUM**

> - Within a language, there is usually a dialect continuum: speakers of Dialect A can understand and be understood by speakers of Dialect B, and C by B, and so on, but at the extremes of the continuum speakers of A and Z may be mutually unintelligible The A and Z communities may therefore feel justified in supposing  or arguing that A and Z are different languages.  If politics intervenes and the speakers of A and Z come to be citizens of different countries, the dialects may well be socially revalued as languages.  [The Oxford Companion to the English Language](http://pt.slideshare.net/felifire/mc-arthur-tom-the-oxford-companion-to-the-english-language-1992)

A good example, covering an extensive area and ignoring political boundaries, would be:

- A - Portuguese
- B - Galego
- C - Asturian
- D - Castilian Spanish
- E - Catalan
- F - Provençal
- G - Piedmontese
- H - Italian

[image]

In a smaller area comprising Sweden and Denmark, which in their standard form are mutually intelligible, there are several dialects:

- A - Norrland
- B - Finland Swedish
- C - Svealand dialects
- D - Gotland dialects
- E - South Swedish dialects
- F - Insular Danish
- G - Jutlandic

A to E in Sweden and F/G in Denmark.

[image][image]

Comment: Is Korean a dialect of Chinese, intercepted by political and historical boundaries?

Comment: @BlessedGeek  No, it's considered a "Language Isolate" with no relation to any other language, just like Basque and maybe Hungarian.

Comment: Korean sinmun, Japanese Shimbun, Mandarin sinwen, Cantonese sunmun. English news. What isolate?

Comment: @BlessedGeek https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_language

Comment: @Centaurus: Hungarian is not an isolate; it's a Uralic language, meaning that it's related to Finnish, Estonian, and various others.

Comment: @ruakh That's why I said "maybe", but you're right, it's not an isolated language.

Comment: All this presupposes a clear difference between "language" and "dialect", which is a political issue and often not objective. Plus normally populations are polyglot.

Comment: You can't depend on Wikipedia on this one. For example, Indonesian/Malay is classified as an austronesian language, but modern Indonesian/Malay is actually based on Sanskrit, and a creolized arabic grammar. Sanskrit, Persian, Urdu and Arabic together form about 80% of the words, with many dutch and spanish words, with a remnant of 10% austronesian words. And writing having shifted from devanagaric derivative to simplified-arabic to latin. And Wikipedia authors still delusionally classify that language as "austronesian". Are people who classify these languages politically motivated?

Comment: @BlessedGeek  I've searched several sites for the origins of Korean Language and most of them agree its origin is obscure.  There are theories, including the so called ["Northern" and "Southern" theories.](http://aboutworldlanguages.com/korean) , http://linguistics.byu.edu/classes/ling450ch/reports/korean3.html , [UCLA](http://lmp.ucla.edu/Profile.aspx?menu=004&LangID=76) but all I could find were theories not universally accepted.

Comment: The only site I found where the phrase "there is agreement"  was used is [The Encyclopaedia Britannica](http://www.britannica.com/topic/Korean-language)  Korean Language isn't the subject of my answer, but I appreciate your question and information.